# Conditional Index in DB2 database

Tags: indexing, db2

Is there a possibility to create a conditional index in db2?

same as in oracle:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON my_table (
  CASE WHEN my_column = 1
       THEN indexed_column
       ELSE NULL
  END);
```

or mssql:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index 
  ON my_table (indexed_column) WHERE my_column = 1
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Something like the first one should work in DB2 if I'm not mistaken. What happened when you tried?

Comment: When I try it i get: 
SQL Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNQ_SINGLE_ACTIV;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<variable_set>, DRIVER=3.57.82

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a contrived example, but I don't see any benefit of an index containing only the values 1 and NULL.

Expression-based indexes are supported beginning with DB2 LUW 10.5. If you are unable to upgrade, you can simulate the behaviour using a computed column (which is what Oracle does behind the scenes anyway).

Comment: This is because I have a flag on each row whether it's active or not and I wanna index only the active records.
Can't upgrade since I need to support different db versions.

Comment: _"I wanna index only the active records"_ - You ain't need to if you collect distribution statistics.

Answer (score 0):

> The uniqueness is also checked during the execution of the CREATE
>   INDEX statement. If the table already contains rows with duplicate key
>   values, the index is not created.